# Convert string to DynaTree object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, dynatree, jquery-dynatree

I am using DynaTree plugin to get the tree structure. Python script returns data to a function in javascipt. I want this data to be used to load children. The data returned by python script is of string datatype. How do I convert it to DynaTree object?

Data returned by python script:

```
    "{title : 'node1'},
    {title : 'node2'},
    {title : 'node3', 
        isFolder: true,
        children : [{title : 'Child'}] }"
```

If this data is stored in a javascript variable(say myVariable), how should I use it?

I have tried

```
    children: [ myVariable ]
    children : myVariable
```

Both dont work. How should I proceed with this?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
children: myVariable
```

and if you start from a list of dics in python,

```
outstring = 'children: %s' % json.dumps(childrenlist)
```

I used `%` because `{}` can be confusing here. Remember to import `json`.